# Text/symbols used in ImageString not showing correctly

Tags: php

I am having a few issues, and have no idea how to work around it and it's been bugging me for days.

I have a script that creates demotivational posters.
(example: http://www.motifake.com/image/demotivational-poster/0901/hey-beetlejuice-doris-joker-funny-demotivational-poster-1231432214.jpg)

The issue I am faced with is the TEXT that is inputted with symbols like:  !@£$%^&*(),.~'

They never show, or come back with different symbols to what they should be, Like a `\`
will be `\\` and a `'` will be `'\`.

I have no special formatting the way the code is used is as follow: 
This is the input field for the text:
    Motivational text: `<input type="text" name="motivationaltext">`

In my PHP file I use:

```
$motivationaltext = $_POST['motivationaltext'];
```

And later on I use this for the image string:

```
CenterImageString($im, $width, $motivationaltext, 16, ($top + $imgy + 74), $text_color);
```

Does anyone have a idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Are you able to post your script? I presume that you're using code from the snippet posted by Dirkjan here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php#94306 - I just ran a quick test with his function and those symbols turn up fine....

Comment: mess-hall.co.uk/Motivator/motivational.zip is the location to the script, And http://mess-hall.co.uk/Motivator/test2.php is it working, But issue with the Symbols 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php.ini file, set [`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). This should take care of the extra `\`.

Alternate solution: if the setting is on and you cannot (or do not want to) turn it off, use the [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function:

```
$motivationaltext = stripslashes($_POST['motivationaltext']);
```